# How to use both GIT and FTP for deployment

Tags: php, git

I'd like to deploy using git, but some members in the team doesn't prefer git and they would like to be able to use ftp, I want us all to be able to access the files and make change. Is there anyway this can happen?

Comment: The repository on the server is actually a folder, so you can give them this kind of access, but this is soooo wrong... Mixing version controlling with file replacement.

Comment: Just use git without these who prefer to deploy with FTP.

Comment: Actually they are Managers :D and that's why I'm seeking the impossibru :D

Comment: Tell them it's not possible and it will mess with the version controlling. Once a file is replaced, the versioning might not be kept.

Comment: It is not a good, but if they are managers... You can allow them to edit files on the server (maybe test server will be a little better), and push changes from this server to the repository by yourself some time.

Comment: @Mohamed Then you're looking for a political solution instead of a technical one. There's a right way, and anything else is going to be a mess. You seem to understand the right way already. Explain this to your managers. Have a paper trace to prove it. Make sure nobody blames you when the inevitable meltdown happens.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an update repository in a ftp server 
then use this repository to deploy via ftp

Answer (score 0):

Using a synchronizer? and exclude git specific files by filter. http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/
You could map the ftp folder.
NetDrive by Novell has a GUI interface for setting up FTP servers as drives on your computer.

Comment: `.gitignore` is for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a test server on which people can go crazy if they want to.
2. Require everyone to commit into a central repository. Seriously, this is a **requirement**.
3. Declare a handful of guys who know what they're doing as "deploy masters" and allow only them to touch the production server, through a clearly defined automated deploy mechanism (git can be fine here).
4. Hack off anyone's hands who still messes directly with production via FTP.